# How to set the exact path to winutils.exe to access HDFS using Java?

Tags: java, windows, hadoop, hdfs, hadoop2

In my system variables, `HADOOP_HOME` is set to `C:\hadoop-2.7.2\bin`

I've tried to access HDFS using the following code:

```
FileSystem hdfs = FileSystem.get(new Configuration());
Path homeDir = hdfs.getHomeDirectory();
```

Runtime Error:

```
17/03/13 10:49:39 ERROR util.Shell: Failed to locate the winutils binary in the hadoop binary path
java.io.IOException: Could not locate executable C:\hadoop-2.7.2\bin\bin\winutils.exe in the Hadoop binaries.
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.getQualifiedBinPath(Shell.java:379)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.getWinUtilsPath(Shell.java:394)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.<clinit>(Shell.java:387)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.StringUtils.<clinit>(StringUtils.java:80)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache$Key.<init>(FileSystem.java:2823)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache$Key.<init>(FileSystem.java:2818)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2684)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:373)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:172)
```

How can I change the path accessed by my code `C:\hadoop-2.7.2\bin\bin\winutils.exe` to `C:\hadoop-2.7.2\bin\winutils.exe` as the former one isn't a valid directory?

Comment: Try setting `HADOOP_HOME` to "C:\hadoop-2.7.2\"?

Comment: Still the same error...

Answer (score 0):

Update `Path variable` as below in screenshot and place `winutils.exe` in `hadoop-2.x/bin/`

[image]

Comment: Added `System.setProperty("hadoop.home.dir", "C:\\hadoop-2.7.2\\");` to my code. It resolved the error but showing the following warning. `WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable`

Comment: Above is just warning, you can run your code without any problem